# how to take key value pair in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb, xsl-fo

How do i define the values in my xsl to populate the key value pair in xsl?

I have tried using the jaxb using the data model defined while we dont have the data model defined how we can populate the data?

My class has input as `HashMap<String,Object>` so if i want to populate some value in xsl how should i get that value in xsl ?

For Example i have key as "item" with value as ItemsList, which has several attributes like item number, item name.

How would i populate it in xsl?

Comment: Stackoverflow didnt allow me to add the additional information so adding in comment. My class has input as HashMap<String,Object> so if i want to populate some value in xsl how should i get that value in xsl ?For Example i have key as "item" with value as ItemsList, which has several attributes like item number,item name. How would i populate it in xsl?

Comment: What do you mean it didn't allow you to add the additional information?

Comment: Weird! when i posted it it didnt showed me all full question, now it shows the full question sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I edited your question to add the stuff that you put here in the comments, but you should be able to click the _edit_ link at any time to make whatever modifications you want.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, and we cannot directly invoke Map in XSL we need to define the bean or Model for it else while creating the xml the marshel will fail.